# Issue when calling a file link with spaces from a QTextBrowser

Tags: html, qt

In Qt, I have a window with a `QTextBrowser`. I successfully open files from links writing HTML as follows:

```
<a href="c:/test.png">test</a> <---- working!
```

but I can't with files with spaces:

```
<a href="c:/te st.png">test</a> <---- not working!
```

I have tried with `te st`, `te+st`, `te&nbsp;st`, and `te%20st`, but still not working...

Does anybody know which solution can I try?

Comment: and if you prepend the filepath with `file:///` and then use `%20`

Comment: Check what `QUrl::fromLocalFile("c:/te st.png")` returns and try with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try with `&nbsp;`? Something like: `<a href="c:/te&nbsp;st.png">test</a>`

**UPDATE:**

It looks like Qt (at least 4.8.x) converts `d:/te st.png` into `d:/te%20st.png` and makes an attempt to execute that string from Windows shell and... fails.

`c:/te&nbsp;st.png` converted to `d:/te%C2%A0st.png` and fails too.

Comment: Okay, I would use anchorClicked for this purpose.